# Is it possible to achieve this level of transparency and saturation with CSS?

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color, photoshop

I'm trying to achieve the same view I have in Photoshop / Avocode with CSS.
But doesn't matter how I overlap the backgrounds and which opacity levels I set - I can't achieve the same level of transparency and saturation.

Is it possible with CSS?

[image]

```css
.parent {
height:300px;
width: 650px;
display:flex;
}

.child {
position:relative;
flex:1;
background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611149956655-0dd788bb763c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80);
background-position: center;
width:50%;
height:100%;
}
.child::after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/*background-color: rgba(102, 207, 235,.7);*/
background-color: rgba(34,186,226, .7);

}
.child1 {
flex:1;
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/t2IIhj1.png);
background-position: center;
width:50%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `mix-blend-mode` can probably help you getting closer:

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 650px;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611149956655-0dd788bb763c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80);
  background-position: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(34, 186, 226, .7);
    mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.child1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/t2IIhj1.png);
  background-position: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's definitely should work! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your needs but can be a way to achieve that.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611149956655-0dd788bb763c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80);
  background-position: center;
}

.parent::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(102, 207, 235);
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" />
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but this way it loses some "clearness" [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wpa1TMl4jtrQutX2FbThwlcdx9LaO9tG/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wpa1TMl4jtrQutX2FbThwlcdx9LaO9tG/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with linear-gradient, placing it in front of an image in background-image. here is the solution:

```css
.parent {
    height:300px;
    width: 200px;
    }
    
    .child {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(102, 207, 235,0.5), rgba(102, 207, 235,0.5)), url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611149956655-0dd788bb763c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80); 
    opacity:1;
    /*
    filter: saturate(2);
    */
    background-position: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can edit the transparency by the last number in the rgba color. I set it to 0.5, you can play with it and find the ideal combination for you. search more about linear gradients, this is some cool stuf for designing :D 
rgba(102, 207, 235,0.5)

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't provide the same look  (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wpa1TMl4jtrQutX2FbThwlcdx9LaO9tG/view?usp=sharing)https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wpa1TMl4jtrQutX2FbThwlcdx9LaO9tG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What look do you exactly want? you can play with the opacity in the rgba colors to find the look you need.

Comment: I updated my question with side by side images, but yes, it looks like "playing with colors" may help. There is no need in gradients tho.
Thank you for the idea!